# How to render PDFs with Play Framework PDF module asynchronously using Jobs?

Tags: playframework

I am sending an email message in Play Framework, and I want to render a PDF file to be used as an email attachment. I have chosen to use Play Framework PDF module, because it uses Play's regular Groovy HTML template system.

I can render the PDF file to ByteArrayOutputStream in my Controller method with following code:

```
PDF.MultiPDFDocuments docs = new PDF.MultiPDFDocuments("myfile.pdf);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
MyEntity myArgument;
PDF.writePDF(os, docs, myArgument);
```

However, I do not like the idea that the PDF rendering is blocking my request processing thread. I would like to render the PDF asynchronously in a Job. The problem is that when I move my code inside a Job, I start getting NullPointerExceptions. This is because the PDF rendering methods of Play PDF module are using extensively Session, Request, Params and Flash objects which were available in the Controller method, but are not available in the Job. For example method play.modules.pdf.PDF.renderTemplateAsPDF has the following lines:

```
templateBinding.put("session", Scope.Session.current());
templateBinding.put("request", Http.Request.current());
templateBinding.put("flash", Scope.Flash.current());
templateBinding.put("params", Scope.Params.current());
```

Is there any way to add Session, Request, Params and Flash information to be securely available for my PDF Job? Or can I somehow prevent the PDF module's rendering methods from calling them? I do not really need the Request and Params information in my template.

Comment: Interesting question. I'll investigate it this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF needs to be rendered in the controller, trying otherwise will give you more headaches than necessary.

You can use asynchronous programming (see [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/asynchronous)). In the example they use generating a *pdf* as an use case :)

Comment: I was also going to post to the link you have identified, but this actually produces the pdf in a job, and returns a Promise, so its not actually done in the controller. I think the example in the document is an example use case, rather than a workable solution using the PDF module.

Comment: @Codemwnci yes you are right, I didn't pay attention to the "job" part of the word :(